# Memcache interesting bug - a:0:{}

Tags: php, memcached, libmemcache

The code is very simple

```
$mem = $this->memcache->get("memche_".$_SESSION['userid']."_page_".$page);

if(empty($mem)){
// to make another query and save the data to memcache
}
else {
// to get it from memcache
}
```

But right now there is no data but cache is not empty if i print_r($mem);
I get

```
a:0:{}
```

And this pass the if statement `if(empty())`

Comment: How do you save your data to memcache? Looks to me  you are saving a serialized array, correct?

Comment: $this->memcache->set("memche_".$_SESSION['userid']."_page_".$page, serialize($data), 0, 60*20); Yes @SiGanteng thats correct

Comment: you're saving serialized array, but you don't unserialize it after getting. `$mem = unserialize($mem); // now empty($mem) === true`

Answer (score 3):

That is not a bug, you have an empty array stored in memcache. Your array is empty, not the variable referencing the array.

```
var_dump(unserialize('a:0:{}'));
array(0) {
}
```

You should be checking if $mem is false ($mem===FALSE), not if it is empty. Memcache returns FALSE if the cache key doesn't exist.

Comment: Still if type if($mem===FAlSE){ echo 1;} in dosent echo the 1 , and the data is string(6) "a:0:{}"

Comment: That is correct because there IS something stored in memcache. The get function will return FALSE if there is NO entry in memcache.